# RMagick not opening multi-page PDFs correctly

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, rmagick

All the RMagick example code I've seen allows opening of multi-page PDFs by using the ImageList class, e.g.

```
page_list = Magick::ImageList.new(pdf_file)
count = 0
page_list.each do |page|
    page.write "image_#{count}.png"
    count += 1
end
```

However, when I load a multi-page PDF into an ImageList, it only returns the first page. What am I doing wrong? Seriously at a loss here. I'm using ImageMagick 6.8.0-10 and Ghostscript 9.07 (via Homebrew) with RMagick 2.13.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the current Homebrew formula for ImageMagick is bogus. It uses 6.8.0-10, while the most recent version is 6.8.5-10. I edited the formula to grab the most recent source by entering `brew edit imagemagick` in a terminal, then replacing the URL and SHA hashes with the following:

```
url 'http://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick-6.8.5-10.tar.gz'
sha256 '1fb8c0eaffb4f67e4f28e46754f3791ae1ffaedbdc7591b8588d618bf854cf45'
```

Uninstall and reinstall (I also had to reinstall RMagick), and ImageList will correctly return an array of pages.